# Concatenating strings from lists in calculated field

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm trying to calculate a field with concatenated strings from zipped lists but I'm having issues with syntax.

```
MyList1 = ['Orange', 'Red']
MyList2 = ['Purple', 'Green']

for x, y in zip(MyList1, MyList2):
    ...##Other code working with x, y
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(InputLyr, "ColorConcat", "Color: {} and Color: {}".format(x, y), "PYTHON_9.3")
    ...##More code working with x, y
```

I'm hoping to get my output, calculated, field to look like this:

```
|          ColorConcat            |
|---------------------------------|
| Color: Orange and Color: Purple |
|  Color: Red and Color: Green    |
```

The only other thing I've tried is using codeblocks, but I don't think that the codeblock will return x and y because they're not global variables. I've also tried simply using `+` to concatenate but I returned the same syntax error.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(InputLyr, "ColorConcat", "Color: " + x + " and Color: " + y, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: Where are you running this code?  From ArcMap, ArcGIS Pro, Python Script Tool, Python Toolbox Tool, Python Addin?  Please review tips on writing [code snippets](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312).  By "zipped lists" do you mean two lists that have items that need to be matched using their order?

Comment: I found how to zip lists at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python - it's a function that I had not noticed before.

Comment: What you show in your first code sample doesn't really make sense. It'll just calculate the `ColorConcat` to be the same x & y value for all the rows and then repeat calculating all the rows for the next x & y value, overwriting the previous calculation.  Are you actually wanting to loop through each row? Does each element in your `MyListN` lists correspond to a row in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the [da.UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) instead of Field Calculator. It is much more powerful and versatile.

```
import arcpy
fc = 'C:\database.gdb\polygons' #Change
colorconcatfield = 'ColorConcat' #Change

MyList1 = ['Orange', 'Red']
MyList2 = ['Purple', 'Green']

colors = zip(MyList1,MyList2)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,colorconcatfield) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        try: 
            row[0] = "Color: {0} and Color: {1}".format(*colors.__next__()) #* is unpacking the tuple of colors
        except StopIteration: #In case there are more rows in fc than colors in lists
            row[0] = "No more colors in lists"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```